# PlaySound too slow on slower PCs?

Tags: c, winapi, playsound

I made a program that outputs a click-sound whenever a key on the keyboard has been pressed.
When I tried the program on my pc (with Ryzen 3900x) and on one of my laptops (with i7 8850h) it outputted the sound flawlessly without any delay, even when typing fast.

But on a slower laptop I use for school, it is not outputting the sound right, especially when typing fast. (The sound is either delayed or it only plays a little part before stopping)

I cant really find an issue other than that PlaySound might be too slow or something. It hasn't anything to do with loading the sound-file, because I am playing the sound from memory. It is also not the recognition of a key-press, because the console output (which key gets pressed) is almost instantly.

Here is my code:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif // UNICODE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <w32api.h>
#define WINVER WindowsXP
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

BYTE* byteAudio = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(uMsg == WM_INPUT)
    {
        HRAWINPUT hRawInput = (HRAWINPUT)lParam;
        RAWINPUT input      = { 0 };
        UINT size           = sizeof(input);
        GetRawInputData(hRawInput, RID_INPUT,&input,&size,sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

        if(input.data.keyboard.Flags == 0)
        {
            //PlaySoundW(TEXT("res/click.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME);
            PlaySound(byteAudio, SND_MEMORY, SND_ASYNC | SND_MEMORY);
            printf("vkey: %x, flag: %d\n",input.data.keyboard.VKey, input.data.keyboard.Flags);
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpComLine, int iShowCmd)
{
    const char* CLASS_NAME = "RawInputClass";
    FILE* fPtr;
    long lFileSize;

    //Gets file size
    fPtr        = fopen("res/click.wav", "rb");
    if(!fPtr)
    {
        printf("Error while opening file!");
        return -1;
    }
    fseek(fPtr, 0, SEEK_END);
    lFileSize   = ftell(fPtr);
    rewind(fPtr);

    //Reads file into byte-Array
    byteAudio = (BYTE*)malloc(lFileSize * sizeof(BYTE));
    if(!byteAudio)
    {
        printf("byteAudio; OUT_OF_MEMORY"); //If that happens, it is probably time for an upgrade
        return -1;
    }
    fread(byteAudio, lFileSize, 1, fPtr);
    fclose(fPtr);

    //Create Message-Only window

    WNDCLASS wnd        = { 0 };
    wnd.hInstance       = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wnd.lpfnWndProc     = WinProc;
    wnd.lpszClassName   = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wnd);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowExW(0, CLASS_NAME, TEXT("THE WINDOW IS INVISIBLE SO WHO CARES!"),
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    RAWINPUTDEVICE rid = { 0 };
    rid.usUsagePage = 0x01;
    rid.usUsage = 0x06; //keyboard
    rid.dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK | RIDEV_NOLEGACY;
    rid.hwndTarget = hWnd;

    RegisterRawInputDevices(&rid, 1, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE));

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why my post is getting downvoted. Please tell me what is wrong about my question so I can edit it accordingly

Comment: SND_MEMORY for the 2nd argument (hMod) is not correct.  PlaySound cannot overlap wave sounds, recalling it during a SND_ASYNC play causes the current play to stop then start again which is probably whats happening.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. According to your description, it may only be related to the computer itself. Maybe you can provide more information for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ZhuSong Is there a way to append files to a question? In that case I could add the click.wav file to the question so you can try it out. Or what kind of information do you mean?

Comment: @Ascendise I think this has nothing to do with the sound file used, maybe you have to find out other possible recurring reasons besides the computer.

Comment: @ZhuSong You said you couldn't reproduce the problem. So it worked on your machine? In that case, may I ask some questions?

- What CPU does your computer have?

- Where you using headphones, plugged in speakers or in-built speakers?

- Did you type on the keyboard like you where about to write a 20 page essay about how bad JAVA is, while it is due in 10min?

Comment: Yes, it works fine for me. I use i7-7700CPU and headphones. I tried to input for a while and it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

You are using a *polling* method, which is slow.

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    /* stuff */
}
```

Read about what *interrupts* are and for what those *interrupts* are used. These will solve your problem.

Comment: Not so. This is the standard Win32 message loop. `GetMessage` blocks until a message is added to the queue.

Comment: This is exactly what a *polling* method does. Maybe I'm blind, but I do not see any *interrupt* routine.

Comment: Introduction to Human Interface Devices (HID): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/ PS the legacy section has also useful informations

Comment: No. This code waits until messages are added to the queue. Then it processes them. Basic fare for windows UI programmers.

Comment: The *"interrupt"* is hidden in the implementation of `GetMessage`. The calling thread isn't scheduled to run until a message becomes available. It's part of Windows' event-driven API, and quite the opposite of *"polling"*.